# Python: Get Module / Class And Function Name of Present Position

Tags: python, logging

In Python, I would like to retrieve the actual name of the module / class / function in a script.

How can I do this?

Background:

I would like to print the name of the module / class / function in the log dynamically.

So my preferred solution would be:

```
my_script.py    

def my_function():
    print (xxxxxx)

    print ("hallo")

my_function()
```

results in:

```
pydev debugger: process 23262 is connecting
my_script.py, my_function
hallo
```

Comment: Check out http://code.activestate.com/recipes/553262-list-classes-methods-and-functions-in-a-module/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def log_name():
    if True:
        print(re.sub(".*/","",str(traceback.extract_stack()[-2])))


def my_function():
    log_name()
```

EDIT:

This gets the call stack via the traceback module and takes the second but last entry. The path is truncated down to name of the module.

Comment: Please add some explanation.